# Get the first src of an image element

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, google-chrome

I am trying to get the first src of the img element in giphy links like this one:
https://media.giphy.com/media/4uZv6yO0loMKc/giphy.gif

I am using this jquery code:

```
$('img').attr('src');
```

but it gets the second source link which ends in .gif and not the one which ends in .webp.

How can I get the specific img src link, the one which ends in .webp?

Comment: Please provide relevant html in the question as per [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[src$='gif']` as in `$("img[src$='gif']:first").attr("src")`

`[src$='gif']` will select one or more element(s) where the `src` ends with `gif`

This is also safer so you don't have to worry about in what order your images are

**demo**

```js
console.log($("img[src$='gif']:first").attr("src"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/4uZv6yO0loMKc/giphy.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing this code in the `console` while that page is open gives me the correct image.

```
document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].src
```

so this one works as well

```
document.querySelector('img').src
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:
`var attribute = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].attributes.src.value;`

Your problem is not jquery selecting different attributes. The src attribute is an object, which has different properties. Selecting the "value" property will return the link ending in `.webp` as your goal is.